# MySQL: How to rank students' scores with the same class id and course

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here I have a table called *Scores*:

| student_id | class_id | course | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 80 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 80 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 75 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | 90 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 85 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | 85 |
| 7 | 2 | 3 | 85 |
| 8 | 3 | 4 | 78 |
| 9 | 3 | 4 | 76 |
| 10 | 3 | 4 | 79 |

What I want to do is to select `student_id`, `class_id`, `course`, `score` and `rank` based on the students' scores. However, we need to separate students into different groups before ranking, which means those students who have the same `class_id` and `course` can be ranked with each other. Plus, we need to sort the results by `class_id`, `course`, `score` and `student_id` in descending order. (You could not use *rank() / partition function* to do the ranking, you could only use subquery)

The results should be like:

| student_id | class_id | course | score | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 3 | 4 | 79 | 1 |
| 8 | 3 | 4 | 78 | 2 |
| 9 | 3 | 4 | 76 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | 90 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | 3 | 85 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | 85 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 75 | 3 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 85 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 80 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 80 | 2 |

My attempt:
I could select `class_id`, `course`, `score` and `student_id` from the table *Scores* in descending order and rank all the students, but I have no idea how to rank the students in the same `class_id` and `course`

Comment: do you have a method of easily reproducing the results?

Comment: Is this an assignment ?  Please post a dbfiddle, it makes it easier for people to respond with a tested functioning answer.  And show us your attempt so far.

Comment: What version of MySQL? Later versions have window functions like [RANK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank). Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Scores (
  student_id int,
  class_id int,
  course int,
  score int
);

insert into Scores (student_id, class_id, course, score)
values ( 1, 1, 1, 80);
insert into Scores (student_id, class_id, course, score)
values ( 2, 1, 1, 80);
insert into Scores (student_id, class_id, course, score)
values ( 3, 2, 3, 75);
insert into Scores (student_id, class_id, course, score)
values ( 4, 3, 2, 90);
insert into Scores (student_id, class_id, course, score)
values ( 5, 1, 2, 85);
insert into Scores (student_id, class_id, course, score)
values ( 6, 2, 3, 85);
insert into Scores (student_id, class_id, course, score)
values ( 7, 2, 3, 85);
insert into Scores (student_id, class_id, course, score)
values ( 8, 3, 4, 78);
insert into Scores (student_id, class_id, course, score)
values ( 9, 3, 4, 76);
insert into Scores (student_id, class_id, course, score)
values (10, 3, 4, 79);

select student_id
  , class_id
  , course
  , score
  , RANK() OVER (
    PARTITION BY class_id, course
    ORDER BY score desc
  ) as "rank"
from Scores
order by class_id desc
  , course desc
  , score desc
  , student_id desc
```

Comment: What makes you think that this requires a static solution ?  Are the tables never going to grow ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "static solution".  Do you mean the sample data I included to demonstrate the query?  Are you saying answers should not include sample DDL and data when the DDL was not provided by the OP?